# When is a homogeneous space connected?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let $G$ be a Lie group (not necessarily connected) and let $H$ be a closed subgroup of $G$. I am after an algebraic (group theoretic) characterization of when the homogeneous space $G/H$ is connected.

I found the following necessary condition in Onishchik/Vinberg, Lie groups and algebraic groups: Let $G_0$ denote the connected component of the identity in $G$ then $G/G_0$ is a discrete group. If $G/H$ as above is connected then $G/G_0$ is isomorphic (as a group) to $H/(H\cap G_0)$.

Does anybody know if this is also sufficient? Onishchik/Vinberg do not give a proof. Any idea of how to go about that? I was quite surprised that I could not find anything relevant on this question in other books (Kobayashi/Nomizu, Helgason, Hilgert/Neeb, ...) and also a google search throws up nothing.

The above necessary condition seems to formalize the intuitive idea that $H$ needs to contain an element from every connected component of $G$ for $G/H$ to be connected.

Ultimately, I want to be able to decide this algorithmically (at least for matrix Lie groups), but this is not part of this question.

Edit: clarified wording, I did not know how to formally link the idea in paragraph four to the quotient group objects when I asked the question

Comment: The group $H/(H\cap G_0)$ can be considered as a subgroup in $G/G_0$. The space is connected if $H/(H\cap G_0)=G/G_0$. Assume  $G/G_0=\mathbb Z$ and $H/(H\cap G_0)=2{\cdot}\mathbb Z$; they are isomorphic but the space has two connected components. (Maybe you want to assume that $G$ is compact?)

Comment: You gave the answer to your question in the 1st sentence of your 4th paragraph.  What else would you like to know?

Comment: I did not know how to formally link the idea about components to the quotient group objects. Todd answers this below. Thanks also to Anton for pointing out the inclusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Ryan says, the idea is in the first sentence of the fourth paragraph, so it's just a matter of formalizing it into a proof.

There is a natural isomorphism $\pi_0(G) \cong G/G_0$ for any Lie group $G$. The inclusion $i: H \to G$ induces by functoriality a function $\pi_0(i): \pi_0(H) \to \pi_0(G)$; by the natural isomorphism it is given by a composite

$$H/H_0 \to H/H \cap G_0 \hookrightarrow G/G_0$$

where the first map is well-defined as $H_0 \subseteq H \cap G_0$ and is clearly an epi. Thus the composite gives the epi-mono factorization of $\pi_0(i)$, and the necessary condition cited in the question (as corrected by Anton Petrunin), which is that the inclusion is onto, is thus sufficient to guarantee that $\pi_0(i)$ is surjective, or that $H$ intersects each path component of $G$ in a nonempty set.

So given $g, g' \in G$, we may pick $h \in H$ so that $g$ and $g'h$ belong to the same path component. Pick a path $\alpha: I \to G$ connecting them; then the composite $I \stackrel{\alpha}{\to} G \stackrel{\pi}{\to} G/H$ is a path connecting $gH$ to $g'H$.